# Java: Optimize two searches and two lists to one

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my program by getting rid of duplicate searches or just by generally make things optimized throughout my program and I came across a method in which I can't find any "better" solution what so ever and would love to know if anyone could point me in a direction for refineing it.

First off here is my code that I'm trying to optimize:

```
public Player spaceBattle(Player player1, Player player2) {
    ArrayList<Ship> listOfShipsPlayer1 = this.getShipsOfPlayer(player1);
    ArrayList<Ship> listOfShipsPlayer2 = this.getShipsOfPlayer(player2);

    Random random = new Random();

    int player1hits = 0, player2hits = 0, rolledDie;

    for (Ship aShip : listOfShipsPlayer1) {
        rolledDie = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        if (rolledDie >= aShip.getShipType().getCombatValue()) {
            player1hits += 1;
        }
    }

    for (Ship aShip : listOfShipsPlayer2) {
        rolledDie = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        if (rolledDie >= aShip.getShipType().getCombatValue()) {
            player2hits += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < player1hits; ++i) {
        if (this.getShipsOfPlayer(player2).size() > 0) {
            this.listOfShips.remove(listOfShipsPlayer2.get(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < player2hits; ++i) {
        if (this.getShipsOfPlayer(player1).size() > 0) {
            this.listOfShips.remove(listOfShipsPlayer1.get(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see here I run the same algorithm twice in order to check for first Player1 and then Player2 and add update their respective hits. And then for the amount of hits for each player I then remove a ship.
What I would like to know if its possible to change this bit of code to be able to not have the duplicate code for each player but that it automatically can go through player1 first and then player2 in one loop.

Looking forward to hear from you

Comment: Would adding a method for each of the algorithms be considered optimization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a working solution looking for improvement, this should be posted on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

You can just create methods.

```
private int hitShips(List<Ship> ships) {
    int result = 0;
    for (Ship ship : ships) {
        rolledDie = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        if (rolledDie >= ship.getShipType().getCombatValue()) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

which makes your code

```
int player1hits = hitShips(listOfShipsPlayer1);
int player2hits = hitShips(listOfShipsPlayer2);
```

and similar for the removal of the ships from the list.

```
void removeShips(List<Ship> ships, int remove) {
    int removeCount = Math.max(ships.size(), remove);
    Iterator<Ship> it = ships.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < removeCount; i++) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

with

```
removeShips(getShipsOfPlayer(player2), player1hits);
removeShips(getShipsOfPlayer(player1), player2hits);
```

I'm not sure why you always remove ships from the head of the lists, since combat values seems to be a thing, but that's just a side note.

I wouldn't call this "optimization" so much, but the removal of duplicate code is always good.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize removeShips as:

```
void removeShips(List<Ship> ships, int numHits) {
  int numToRemove = Math.min(ships.size(), numHits);
  if (numToRemove > 0) {
    ships.subList(0, numToRemove).clear();
  }
}
```

This method call will result in only one `System.arraycopy` call, which will shift all remaining elements to the left.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-